# Jenkins SSH Plugin, transfer only changed files

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job where at the end a file transfer of the entire workspace to another server, on that I will start the application, is performed.
My application is a Ruby on Rails project, so I have a lot of different files to transfer.
And of course not every file is needed to be transferred because there was no change to it, but the SSH plugin does it anyway.

Is there a configuration or other plugin where I can change this behavior?
That would especially be interesting for other project with much bigger files.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on **Linux** you can use [rsync](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html) to transfer your files to the remote server.

> rsync is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the
>   amount of data sent over the network by sending only the differences
>   between the source files and the existing files in the destination.

Therefore it will not transfer the entire workspace but just the files that have been changed, deleted or added.

As for Jenkins you can add a **Execute Shell** as a **Build** step and then rsync your workspace to the remote server over ssh.

For example:

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p <post_no>' <path/to/project/workspace/> <username>@<server_ip>:<target/path/to/transfer>
```

If you need some more information for rsync over ssh read [this](https://kyup.com/tutorials/copy-files-rsync-ssh/) link.

For **Windows** you can use a windows alternative of rsync like [cwrsync](https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync).

Comment: Thank you. That's a very nice alternative, although I had some issues with my private key (permission denied error). Turns out it was not readable because ssh wants 600 permission on the file and the user trying to read was not root, which was set for this file (I needed jenkins). After fixing that, it works like a charm out of Jenkins.